# Why should not I use browser storage to share data between controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am aware that I can use a service or factory to share data or I can also use the $rootScope,or $scope.$broadcast but I am avoiding to use $broadcast as my controllers do not have parent-child heirarchy. Both lie at the same level of scope heirarchy, and $rootScope is not considered safe. But what is the problem if I have to share **small** objects via browser storage, and as soon as the intended controller has gathered the object,I can delete the object from browser storage. Something like this:

```
app.controller('frstCtrl', function($window){
$scope.data = {'msg':'hi now brown cow'};
$window.localStorage.temp = angular.toJson($scope.data);


});

app.controller('secCtrl', function($window){
$scope.data = $window.localStorage.temp;
delete $window.localStorage.temp;

});
```

So could anyone please tell me the downides of doing this?

Comment: Why do you think a service can't be used to do the same thing? The lack of parent-child relationship is irrelevant. A service is a singleton, and two controllers using the same service share a reference to a unique instance, whatever their relationship (or lack of relationship) is. Also, localStorage is global to the browser, so two tabs executing the same application would step on each other's toes.

Comment: Yes it can definitely be used. No issues in that. I just asked this for my curiosity to know what could be wrong with using browser storage. And thanks to you I got a downside of using browser storage.

Comment: Well, there's the fact that localStorage is global, and there's the fact that you don't store on disk something that just needs to exist in memory. You can, but it shows a lack of understanding, and it's less efficient.

Comment: That sums it up I guess! Thanks for your answer sire. That really clears up my doubt.